# Should we keep [tag:electromagnetic]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

This tag seems at least ambiguous to me, besides the fact that it's so generic that it could include anything on this site.

Ambiguous because otoh it can include at least:

- electromagnetic switch (i.e. [solenoid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solenoid));
- electromagnetic fields ([field](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field));
- electromagnetic radiation ([radiation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation)).

In short, I suggest to just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

While your at it, you might want to have a look at [electromagnetisim](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism)  The average rep of a user posting on one of these tags is less than 30, and 20% to 30% of the questions tagged with

I would be more supportive of merging these tags and coming up with a better tag description.

One of the main reasons for this is one of the major site topics is:

> ["the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

so if you have no electromagnetic tag then there would be no way to group questions about electromagnetic forces under one banner.

I would like to see a better tag description, maybe I'll write one later. But at least merge [electromagnetic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic) and [electromagnetism](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) or just move some of the best electromagnetic questions to electromagnetism and delete electromagnetic.